# How to pass arguments to sbt in a jenkinsfile

Tags: java, scala, jvm, sbt, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to launch a clean assembly step with sbt into a jenkinsfile. I use the following step:

```
sh "${tool name: 'sbt-0.13.13', type: 'org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SbtPluginBuilder$SbtInstallation'}/bin/sbt clean assembly -J-Dhttps.proxyHost=my-http-proxy -J-Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Xmx1g -Xms2g "
```

But it seems that it does not work because of the Xms argument which is not override even if I give it in the command above. The output is as follow:

```
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] sh
[workspace] Running shell script
+ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SbtPluginBuilder_SbtInstallation/sbt-0.13.13/bin/sbt clean assembly -J-Dhttps.proxyHost=egress-http-proxy -J-Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -J-Xmx1g -J-Xms2g
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true
Invalid initial heap size: -Xms7g-
Dorg.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pipeline.PodTemplateStepExecution.defaultImage=172.30.37.22:5000/openpaas/jenkins-slave-jnlp:release
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Do you have any idea why my argument is not used or do you have any solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem of the above code came from the wrong formating line :

```
-Xms7g-Dorg.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pipeline.PodTemplateStepExecution.defaultImage=172.30.37.22:5000/openpaas/jenkins-slave-jnlp:release
```

which miss a space between -Xms7g and -Dorg.csanchez.
To pass arguments, you want to use the following command and prefix arguments with -J:

```
sh "${tool name: 'sbt-0.13.13', type: 'org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SbtPluginBuilder$SbtInstallation'}/bin/sbt clean assembly -J-Dhttps.proxyHost=my-http-proxy -J-Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -J-Xmx1g -J-Xms2g "
```